# Clear console screen in Java

Tags: java, console

Is there any option to clear the console screen in Java as clrscr() in C?

Comment: Clear *what* screen? Are you talking about a console application?

Comment: yes about the console application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As dirty hacks go, I like msparer's solution.  An even dirtier method that I've seen used (I would never do this myself.  I swear.  Really.) is to write a bunch of newlines to the console.  This doesn't clear the screen at all, but creates the illusion of a clear screen to the user.

```
char c = '\n';
int length = 25;
char[] chars = new char[length];
Arrays.fill(chars, c);
System.out.print(String.valueOf(chars));
```

Comment: I didn't dare to write this answer down. Nice :-)

Comment: @LB: I admit this is probably the *worst* way to do it.  Sometimes you just have to share your WTFs. :)

Comment: How is this different than

`System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");`

which is one line instead of five?

Comment: @Tenner: My code could be written as a function with the char and length passed in.  Other than that, no real difference.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about the console, then no.  Writing to the console is just a special case of an output stream.  Output streams don't know anything about the screen, as they can be just as easily redirected to a file or another system device.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about a console application, then there isn't a clear screen option AFAIK. A **quite dirty** option would be to invoke the clear screen command of the underlying OS.

Then it's something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

for Windows or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
```

for a load of other OS. You can find out the OS with `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

Comment: it is not working. i tried in windows xp.

Comment: I think `cls` is a built-in function, not an actual executable.

Comment: Trying this option I simply get `error: unreported exception IOexception; must be caught or declared to be thrown.`

Comment: `cls` would never work for it is not an inbuilt command. Try using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cls");`

Comment: This [does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379766/9092024), and apparently does not work even in WSL (Ubuntu) as I'm finding out now.

Answer (score 6):

For any console which supports ANSI escapes the following would work (would e.g. work in Win98 console).

```
private final String ANSI_CLS = "\u001b[2J";
....
System.out.print(ANSI_CLS);
System.out.flush();
...
```

Starting with Win NT this won't work anymore and you can either

- Do a JNI call (e.g. like here: [Java: Clear console and control attributes](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0047.html)
- Or write out a bunch of empty lines

Otherwise you are out of luck.

And btw. you must keep in mind that `System.out` and `System.err` don't have to be console they could be set to what ever (writing into a file e.g.) an usecase where clearing the screen wouldn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 4):

On linux, you can do something like:

```
System.out.println("\f");
```

You can also use [Jcurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)

Answer (score 3):

To clear the screen just type:

```
System.out.print('\u000C');
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows

Answer (score 3):

You can also try ANSI Escape Codes:

If your terminal support them, try something like this:

```
System.out.print("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
```

You can include `\0333[1;1H` to be sure if `\0333[2J` does not move the cursor in the upper left corner.

More specifically:

- `033` is the octal of `ESC`
- `2J` is for clearing the entire console/terminal screen
- `1;1H` moves the cursor to row 1 and column 1

Comment: This is the only ANSI-solution which consistently works inside my Linux terminal. Especially the cursor repositioning at the end makes it look nice and clean. Moreover, it respects the size (height) of the window.

Answer (score 2):

**Jansi** is an excellent workaround. I am an amateur coder and Jansi is easy to setup especially with Eclipse.

The following is a link to the homepage of Jansi:

http://jansi.fusesource.org/

The following is a link to a site containing a code as a demonstration of AnsiConsole class contained in the Jansi package:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0047.html

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, [Java Console API](http://code.google.com/p/java-console-api/) project provides functionality to determine console size and set cursor position. Clearing the screen is trivial with that. It's a version 0.2 now so it's not exactly production ready, but it works.

Alternatively, you can simply print out some new lines via `System.out.println()`. 640 should be enough for everybody :-) It's not the same as clearing screen, but for user's intents and purposes it'd do.

Answer (score 0):

you should give a try with JNA and try mapping native libraries:

- on linux you must map C functions from **ncurses** library
- on windows you must map functions from both **msvcrt** and **kernel32**, as clearly stated [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816180)

PS

let me known if you need some sample code