# How to clear previous in the terminal from a command line Java program

Tags: java, input

I am new in Java and have one, I think, simple question on which I can not find an answer (May be my google is not working properly :) ).

I have a task to create some application, before it proceed to start, user should input some information in console, for example:

```
[devel@edu-cs-tpl bank_side]$  ./crypto.sh -i
Enter number of ZMK components (1 - 9): 2
Enter ZMK component 1: 1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
Enter ZMK component 2: 4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
Enter ZEK under ZMK:
```

I am using java.util.Scanner to make this input. Is it possible on Java to "hide" the componnet inputed before last? I mean:

1)

```
[devel@edu-cs-tpl bank_side]$  ./crypto.sh -i
Enter number of ZMK components (1 - 9): 2
Enter ZMK component 1: 1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
```

2)

```
[devel@edu-cs-tpl bank_side]$  ./crypto.sh -i
Enter number of ZMK components (1 - 9): 2
Enter ZMK component 2: 4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a4a
```

Please advice how can i do that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: seems your question is wired. 1st one you are executing crypto.sh once but in 2nd you are doing each time. my answer is for second one.

Comment: Do you mean just write over a previous line, or do you mean make it so the input is never since (like a password prompt). Under unix you could write a carriage return (`"\r"`) followed by lots of spaces to hide previous input.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the argument at runtime by command line argument.

Also look at [clear screen option in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682212/clear-screen-option-in-java)
Above link indicates there is no straight forward way to do what you are looking for.