# clear screen of cmd with java?

Tags: java, directory

Can we clear the cmd screen while making console application with java code.In c or c++ we use clrscr() method but in what code we need to do it in java?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Java does not provide any such functionality. Output on terminal is just a special case of redirecting standard output(standard input or standard error). As such output stream has no knowledge what the stream is redirected to.

You can use hacks to achieve your goal though. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682212/clear-screen-option-in-java). Best way I thing is the following

```
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

    if (os.contains("Windows"))
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
    }
    else
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
    }
```

Comment: *"Cannot run program "cls": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"* - Windows 7, Java 7

Comment: Surprising works fine in my CentOS with java7

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("\033[2J\n");
```

This shall do it :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Windows 7, Java 7

Comment: whats your compiler..blue J?

Comment: if its blueJ then try System.out.println("\f");

Comment: Plain on Java 7, tried `System.out.println("\f");` from another answer, didn't work :P

Answer (score 0):

Printing out the form-feed character will clear the screen

```
System.out.print("\f");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

You can use this code

```
private static void Clear()
{
    try
    {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

        if (os.contains("Windows"))
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```