# How to clear the screen in java in cmd

Tags: java

How to clear the screen in the Java
loke `clrscr()` command in c.

I am use the command prompt to run the program.

Please put the code:

```
class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
        //clear scrren hear
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Also use Runtime class but thats not work pls give the same code to perform this.

Also using this code but not work:

```
     import java.io.*;  
       class demo
{
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {   
        try
{
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

    if (os.contains("Windows"))
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
    }
    else
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
}
        //clear scrren hear
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682212/clear-screen-option-in-java

Comment: Why don't you google it...

Comment: Because that all code not worked

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
Console console = System.console();        
console.clear();
```

Comment: There is not clear event in Console class please check it out