# How can I print something in the same line as the user input?

Tags: java, printing, user-input

I wrote this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main (String[] args){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
   String inp;
   int m;
   System.out.println ("Please enter some characters.");
   inp = scan.nextLine();
   m = inp.length();
   System.out.println(" = " + m);
}
```

If I run that, I get something like this:

```
Please enter some characters.
12345
 = 5
```

But how can I get the `= 5` to be printed on the same line as the characters entered by the user, like below?

```
Please enter some characters.
12345 = 5
```

Comment: If you mean on the command line, the answer is no.

Comment: As an explanation to Gumbo's comment, this wouldn't be possible on the command line (e.g. using a `Scanner` and `System.in`) because Java doesn't even see the input until the user hits `ENTER`, which forces the `= 7` to be on another line.

Comment: You could always remember the input, clean the console and print input + output together, couldn't you?

Comment: Similar: [User input on same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28011420)

Answer (score 2):

There is no function in standard Java that allows you to easily do this.

You will need to interact with the terminal using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). This is not supported by all terminals.

You could also use a library that will do this for you, some examples in random order:

- [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/)
- [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna)
- [Java Curses Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses)

Comment: I can't help you if you don't tell me what part you don't understand.

Comment: I don't get that "You need to interact with the terminal you are using."

Answer (score -1):

```
 System.out.print("Please enter some characters.");
 inp = scan.nextLine();
 m = inp.length();
 System.out.println(" = " + m);
```

When you print the question, remove the ln part (`System.out.print("Please enter....)`)
This will allow your input to be on the same line as the prompt.
Then you can print `System.out.println( inp + " = " + m);`
However you can't type something after the input as far as i know but you can echo it.