# String Replace After Waiting Time

Tags: java, string, multithreading

Edit: code has been solved. This solution has only been tested to work for cmd. That is, it may not work for Eclipse.

The corrected code is now:

```
String code = "Generating code...\r";
String successful = code.replaceAll("Generating code...\r", "Generating the code has been successful.\r");
```

Original Issue: 
I want to be able to display a String for two seconds, then after waiting two seconds, I then want that String to be replaced by another String.

I have attempted a basic structure, but it does not appear to replace the code, and instead appears below it.

Code:

```
String code = "Generating code...\n\n";
String successful = code.replaceAll("Generating code...\n\n", "Generating the code has been successful.\n\n");

[...]
try {
      System.out.print(code);
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.print(successful);
    }

catch(InterruptedException e) {
                 [...]
        }
```

What this code does currently is print Generating Code... then after two seconds it will print Generating the Code has been successful... on two new lines.

However, instead of it printing two new lines down, I want the String Generating the Code has been successful to overwrite the String Generating Code... only after the two second have elapsed.

Comment: You would have to 'clear the screen' in order to replace the String? Printing it two new lines down is the expected behavior.. Clearing screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682212/clear-screen-option-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is printing out to the console.
Your replace() doesn´t do anything.
If you have to print over the old output you can use \r to jump back to the beginning of the current line.(Make sure to use print, not println!)

Like this:

```
String code = "Generating code...\r";
String successful = "Generating the code has been successful.\r"

[...]
try {
    System.out.print(code);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.print(successful);
}

catch(InterruptedException e) { [...] }
```

Known Bug: This might not work in Eclipse!

Comment: It should work just fine, but there might be "errors" when running it with eclipse.

Comment: @Lucky's Yeah, it didn't work with Eclipse. Does it work when running it on cmd?

Comment: @Gosu just tested it with cmd, working like it should be

Comment: @Lucky's Okay, maybe you should add a note in your answer (i.e. doesn't  work in Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just clear the console as per Gosu's comment then take a look at this post [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console).

If you had some sort of graphical user interface than you would change the text of the graphical widget.